WebDriverWait not waiting for a specific check to happen
I'm having issues trying to get a webpage to open which leads to a log in page, I wanted the code to simply wait for me to log into URL1 and when thats done the next piece of the script runs and opens a new tab to a new URL. My issue is it opens and runs chrome, goes to the first URL log in page just fine, but at the same time opens the second URL page that i want it to wait for
this is what im working with, im new at this im trying to take answers from what I read across this site and many others but I cant seem to find one that works for me so I'm sorry if my code looks very weird or armature-like
service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get("URL1")
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-button")))
driver.execute_script("window.open('URL2')")
while True:
    print("Browser is open. Press Ctrl+C to close.")
    try:
        input()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

I thought that
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-button"))) 

was suppose to wait for an element to disappear like the "Login-button" and once it notices that, it runs the script
driver.execute_script("window.open('URL2')") 

to open the next URL I wanted
again, the problem is that both URL1 and URL2 are opening at the same time when I run this, its not waiting for me to log in first or making any checks etc.
